# Add a computed column from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So here is the thing:

I have a table called Reward:

```
CustomerID OrderID OrderRewardPoints ExpireDate
    #1        1        55             2014-09-26#
    #1        2        145            2014-09-27#
    #2        3        70             2014-09-27#
```

I want to add a column RewardPoints, which computed by all different CustomerID and how many OrderRewardPoints they have.

Like CustomerID 1, he has two OrderRewardPoints, so the new column for him is 200.

And by using select I can get the result but I just don't know how to add as a new column.

```
SELECT SUM (OrderRewardPoints) AS RewardPoints
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: You should add the column to the `Customer` table, not the `Reward` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the column:

```
alter table reward
add rewardpoints int;
```

To populate the column:

```
update reward t
   set rewardpoints =
       (select sum(x.orderrewardpoints)
          from reward x
         where x.customerid = t.customerid);
```

You would probably be better served by creating a view which shows the total reward points for each customer, rather than physically adding a column to the reward table, which would require updates.

To do that you could run:

```
create view rewardtotals_vw as
select customerid, sum(orderrewardpoints) as rewardpoints
  from reward
 group by customerid
```

Comment: Though this isn't really a computed column in the usual SQL Server sense as it isn't maintained automatically (not possible to use a persisted computed column for this though an un persisted poor performing version can be achieved with a scalar UDF)

Comment: I was just answering literally, he should probably create a view, or have a reporting table with one row per customer and their total that gets refreshed however often necessary

Comment: I think you are right, I probably should create a new table about the total rewardpoints. It seems more complicated than just a computed column.